# How to deal with "false = true" proposition while proving theorems in coq

Tags: coq, proof, theorem

I am new to coq and trying to prove this theorem

```
Inductive expression : Type :=
  | Var (n : nat)
.
.

Theorem variable_equality : forall x : nat, forall n : nat,
  ((equals x n) = true) -> (Var x = Var n).
```

This is the definition of equals

```
Fixpoint equals (n1 : nat) (n2 : nat) :=
  match (n1, n2) with
    | (O, O)      => true
    | (O, S n)    => false
    | (S n, O)    => false
    | (S n, S n') => equals n n'
  end.
```

This is my solution so far

```
Proof.
intros x n. induction x as [| x' IH].
  - destruct n. 
    + reflexivity.
    + simpl. intro.
```

and I end up with something like this

```
1 subgoal 
n : nat
H : false = true
-------------------------
Var 0 = Var (S n)
```

I understand that this output means that the proposition "Var 0 = Var (S n)" should follow from the proposition "false = true" if the theorem has to be correct, but I don't know what to do about it and move ahead with my proof.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, `discriminate` which is the dedicated tactic for this kind of goals: it is supposed to solve exactly this kind of problems (i.e. equalities of distinct constructors in your hypotheses) and no more.

```
Goal false = true -> False.
discriminate.
Qed.
```

Additionally, it is a **terminator**, which means it fails if the goal is not solved after its use, contrarily to `inversion` and `congruence` which will succeed in some cases where they do not solve the expected problem and succeed in an "unexpected" way.

e.g.

```
Goal true = true -> True.
inversion 1.
Qed.
```

and

```
Goal true = true -> S 1 = S 1.
congruence.
Qed.
```

Personally, I use `by []` (which is also a terminator) from ssreflect for this kind of goals and for all "trivial" goals of the sort:

```
Require Import ssreflect.

Goal false = true -> False.
by [].
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option: instead of `inversion`, use `congruence`:

```
Goal false=true -> False.
  congruence.
Qed.
```

This tactic is dedicated to exploiting disjointness of constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inversion` on such hypothesis as in:

```
Goal false=true -> False.
intros H.
inversion H.
Qed.
```