# How do I prove false from a false hypothesis?

Tags: coq, proof, coqide

I have a hypothesis that is clearly wrong and I would like to use that to prove False. In this case I have `Hx: 0 * 0 = 2` and I have `False` in my goal. How would I start to do it?

Image from CoqIDE:
[image]

Comment: `trivial` should work

Comment: Another solution: `discriminate` (as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66842087/how-to-deal-with-false-true-proposition-while-proving-theorems-in-coq/66869782#66869782)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `easy` tactic:

```
Goal 0 * 0 = 2 -> False. Proof. easy. Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

A manual approach, for completeness:

```
Goal 0 * 0 = 2 -> False.
Proof.
  intro H.
  inversion H.
Qed.
```

(Disclaimer: I'm a relative beginner at Coq myself, so apologies if I get any details incorrect—please let me know so I can improve the answer!)

This works because `0 * 0 = 2` evaluates to `0 = 2`, and inverting that hypothesis breaks it down into its different possible constructors (like a smarter version of `destruct`). The only possible constructor for `eq` is `eq_refl : forall a, a = a`. So, Coq realizes that `eq_refl` is the only possible constructor that could have been used to make a hypothesis of the form `0 = 2`. As such, Coq will try to find the value of `a`, as part of the inversion process. But, applying this to `0 = 2`, it gets `x = 0` *and* `x = 2`! Because `0 = O` and `2 = S (S O)` are made up of entirely different constructors, Coq recognizes this as a contradiction and considers your proof complete.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution for completeness: `cbn ; congruence`. Indeed `0 * 0` *reduces* to 0 (i.e. `O`), which is different from 2 (`S (S O)`) by *disjointness of the constructors* of the type `nat`. The first tactic reduces (simplifies) the goal, the second one exploits disjointness to deduce the contradiction.

```
Goal 0 * 0 = 2 -> False.
  cbn. congruence.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet *another* solution, which applies in this specific example: `lia`. `lia` stands for **L**inear **I**nteger **A**rithmetic. This powerful tactic considers all hypotheses consisting of, well, linear integer arithmetic (be it equations or inequalities) and uses them to solve an arithmetic goal, or any goal if the arithmetic hypotheses are contradictory.

You have to load a library.

```
Require Import Coq.micromega.Lia.

Goal 0 * 0 = 2 -> False.
  lia.
Qed.
```

With Coq there are always a bunch of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand how it works "behind the scenes", [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730456/304284) may be useful.