# How can I handle this `false = true` case?

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove the following lemma.

```
Inductive bool : Type :=
  | true
  | false.

Lemma andb_true_iff : forall b1 b2 : bool,
  b1 && b2 = true <-> b1 = true /\ b2 = true.
Proof.
  intros.
  split.
  - intros. split.
    + destruct b1.
      * reflexivity.
      * discriminate.
    + destruct b2.
      * reflexivity.
      * simpl.
```

And now I get

```
1 goal
b1 : bool
H : b1 && false = true
______________________________________(1/1)
false = true
```

This is very absurd, since `false = true` is never True. However, I can't discriminate this goal.

OK, maybe we should prove `H` to be False, which is exact `false = true`. We can't reject to prove a goal which we believe to be False. However, why can't I even rewrite this goal to `False`? Is it because we have not proved it yet? So I prove the following

```
Lemma false_true: (false = true) -> False.
Proof.
  intros.
  simpl in H.
  discriminate H.
Qed.
```

And seems the `Lemma false_true` can't be applied to this goal. Instead, I know I can write the following lemma to perform a rewrite

```
Lemma false_true2: (false = true) = False.
Proof. Admitted.
```

However, I think `false_true` and `false_true2` are somehow very similar. Is there any way that instead of rewrite by `false_true2`, we can just apply `false_true`?

Or must I write the following to apply?

```
Lemma false_true3: False -> (false = true).
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H.
Qed.
```

== NOTE ==

I have solved this problem by destructing `b1` either. However, I want to know is there any way to resolve `false = true`, since it looks weird to me.

Comment: It's unclear if you are using the Stdlib or not, since you show a definition of `bool` instead of requires and imports, on the other hand you don't define `andb` nor any notation, so I'd guess you do are using the Stdlib...  Then the point is, with the Stdlib there are lemmas available that would make the proof of the theorem above quite shorter.   Or, are you interested in proving it from "first principles"?

Answer (score 1):

In the current case, it appends that the `_ && _` returns the value `false` when the second argument is `false`.   This is given by a theorem available in the `Bool` library.  You can find this theorem using the `Search` command.

```
Require Import Bool.

Search (_ && false).
```

The result shows.

```
andb_false_r : forall b : bool, b && false = false
```

rewriting with this theorem in your hypothesis `H` returns and hypothesis of the form.

```
`false = true`
```

In general, when such a hypothesis appears, you can finish by using the tactics like `easy` or `discriminate`, but here, the goal's conclusion has exactly the same statement, so you can even use `assumption`.

Of course, in this case, I am not using a new definition of the type `bool`, rather I rely on existing knowledge, but you initial posting is ambiguous on this matter, because you show a definition of `bool`  (which would be different from the one used in the standard library), but you do not show a definition of `andb`, so we have to assume you are using the standard version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that you cannot prove in the goal, but contradictions in the assumptions, such as False, then you can just ignore the goal, and use the contradictions, because  "ex falso quodlibet", from False follows anything.

In Coq's logic, falsehood is usually represented as assuming that you have a value from an empty set, a value that cannot possibly be created, or that two values with different constructors are the same (the latter is false because constructors are defined to be injective).

The proof is usually done by considering the cases that could have caused those (impossible) values end up as assumptions, and since there are zero ways for that, you dont have any cases to consider, and the goal is proved.

For example, if you have a term `H : False` in your assumptions you can just do `destruct H`.  If you have `false = true` (which are two different constructors of values of type `bool`) then you can use `inversion`.

Also check out [How to prove False from obviously contradictory assumptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286679/how-to-prove-false-from-obviously-contradictory-assumptions/49730456#49730456) and [How do I prove false from a false hypothesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66846765/how-do-i-prove-false-from-a-false-hypothesis/66857326)

By the way, note that `false` (a value) is not the same as `False` (a type or proposition),

and it is not possible to prove `(false = true) = False`. However you can prove `false = true <-> False`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `bool` is a special type in Coq which is encoded in the as you suggested:

```
Inductive bool : Type :=
  | true
  | false.
```

However, the notation `_&&_` is something special if you try to `Locate "&&"`:

```
Notation
"x && y" := andb x y : bool_scope (default interpretation)
```

where `andb: bool -> bool -> bool` is something that you cannot simply `discriminate` on as this tactic only works on explicit *type constructors*. In your case (I am assuming that you are importing `Bool` from Coq's stdlib), `a && b` is a type returned by a function and Coq has no idea if `a = false` then this term would be `false`.

Quoting

> OK, maybe we should prove H to be False, which is exact false = true. We can't reject to prove a goal that we believe to be False. However, why can't I even rewrite this goal to False?

No. Coq does not know `H: False` implies `false = true`. You need to *prove* it. Or more generally, you have to convince Coq that `a && b = true` implies `a = true /\ b = true`. Fortunately, this theorem is provided by `Bool.andb_true_iff` with which you can eliminate `H` into `b1 = true` and `false = true`. Then you can destruct `H` and use `discriminate` since `false = true` never holds by looking at the constructors of `bool` type.

A warm tip: you should be aware of `False` and `false` and corresponding `&&` and `/\` because they are totally different: `False` is defined at the `Prop` level whereas `false` is just a type constructor for `bool`, which is just a vanilla type.