# How to prove an absurd rule in Coq

Tags: coq

I have to prove the following statement, however I am getting the error `The type of H is not inductive.` when trying to use `inversion` statement:

[image]

How can I do that correctly?

```
Variables phi: Prop.
Section absurd_rule.
Hypothesis H1: phi -> true = false.
Lemma absurd_rule: ~phi.
Proof.
intro H.
inversion H.
End absurd_rule.
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66842087/how-to-deal-with-false-true-proposition-while-proving-theorems-in-coq/66869782#66869782. and https://stackoverflow.com/q/29286679/304284

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inversion` is not the right rule to be used here, as there is nothing to invert on `H : phi`.

Let's take a pause after you `intro H`:

```
H1 : phi -> true = false
H : phi
______________________________________(1/1)
False
```

First of all, note that `H1 H : true = false` (simple application). Let's take advantage of it by writing `apply H1 in H`:

```
H : true = false
______________________________________(1/1)
False
```

Almost there! Now, it is necessarily contradictory that `true = false`, and that's because of conflicting constructors.
There is a dedicated rule to deal with such cases, namingly `discriminate H`.

No more subgoals, we are there. The full proof session looks like this:

```
Variables phi: Prop.
Section absurd_rule.

Hypothesis H1 : phi -> true = false.

Lemma absurd_rule : ~phi.
Proof.
intro H.
apply H1 in H.
discriminate H.
Qed.
```

---

Also, worth noting that you can use `False` to describe bottom (lowercase `false` is a different thing -- an inductive boolean, instead of an empty `Prop`).

A simpler version of your proof would be just

```
Variables phi: Prop.
Section absurd_rule.

Hypothesis H1 : phi -> False.

Lemma absurd_rule : ~phi.
Proof.
assumption.
Qed.
```

...which is not a big discovery, because you just assumed `phi` to be false.

#### After a second of reflection...

You can't "prove a rule". Rules are semantics of the language, laws you use to derive conclusions from assumptions. They are not "theorems" to be proven, but a sort of prior reasoning you use to manipulate sentences. They are even distinct from axioms, it's something on the meta level. You can prove an implication, but not a deduction rule.

Thus, the "solution" to your problem is just an identity. Your `absurd_rule` is just a lemma that `not phi` implies `not phi`, which is trivially true -- remember that in intuitionistic logic negation is very often **defined as** to imply false.